# Loop through list of stocks in yfinance

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, stock, yfinance, ticker

I want to loop through a long list of stocks in yfinance  My while loop is picking up only the first ticker symbol and info.  Why won't it iterate? thru all of the list?

```
symbols = pd.read_csv("symbol_list_short.csv")

counter = 0
while counter <= len(symbols):
   
    for symbol in symbols:
        stock = yf.Ticker(symbol)
        try:
            if stock.info['pegRatio']:
                print(str(stock.info['symbol'] + " : " + str(stock.info['pegRatio'])))
        except KeyError:
                pass
counter += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several reasons why the code above does not work from what I can tell.

1. counter += 1 needs to be indented
2. counter += 1 is known to fail in Python so it is safer to use counter=counter+1
3. yfinance seems to be having problems in accessing Yahoo Finance data [image: OutputFromYourCode]
4. You may need to use another vendor and compute PEG yourself.
5. The code snippet (and output) below reflects Financial Modelling Prep Cloud

```py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import fmpsdk # Financial Modeling Prep (FMP)
import pandas as pd
#import yfinance as yf

# Actual API key is stored in a .env file.  
load_dotenv()
apikey = os.environ.get("apikey")

symbols=["AAPL","MSFT","GOOGL"]
counter = 0
print("\n\nTicker\t\t\tEPS\t\t\tREVENUE")
while counter < len(symbols):
    stock = fmpsdk.historical_earning_calendar(apikey=apikey, symbol=symbols[counter], limit=limit) #yf.Ticker(symbol)
    try:
        if stock[0]["symbol"] in symbols:
            print(str(stock[0]["symbol"] + ": \t\t\t" + str(stock[0]["eps"]) + "\t\t" + str(stock[0]["revenue"])))
    except KeyError:
            pass
    counter = counter + 1
```

```
OUTPUT
Ticker          EPS         REVENUE
AAPL:           1.88        117154000000
MSFT:           2.32        52747000000
GOOGL:          1.05        76048000000
```